# Responsive Div Height Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make replica of one wordpress page using bootstrap. Original Page is looking like this
[image]

However my page is looking like this

[image]

I want remove unnecessary white space below form. My code is like below

```
<div class="container-login100">
    
    <div class="wrap-login100 ">
    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-32">
                    Make Fast Cash Anywhere
    </span>
    
    <span class="login100-form-sub-title p-b-32">
                    Begin Your Fast Start Steps Below...
    </span>
    
    <div class="test-progress" style="background-color:#ebebeb;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success  progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:4%; background-color:#00c479;"><span id="progress">&nbsp;&nbsp;0% </span></div>
    </div>
    
        <form class="login100-form">
            
            <div id="quiz">
          
                <div class="question">
                    <h3>
                    <span id="question"> Are you looking for a way to make money online?</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
               <ul class="text-center" style="list-style-position: inside">
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a-option" name="selector" value="1">
                    <label for="a-option" class="element-animation">Yes</label>
                    <div class="check"></div>
                  </li>
                  
                 
                  
                  <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b-option" name="selector" value="3">
                    <label for="b-option" class="element-animation">No</label>
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li id="lic" style="display:none">
                    <input type="radio" id="c-option" name="selector" value="3">
                    <label for="c-option" class="element-animation">C</label>
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li id="lid" style="display:none">
                    <input type="radio" id="d-option" name="selector" value="3">
                    <label for="d-option" class="element-animation">D</label>
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css code is like below

```
.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.container-login100 {
  width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url("../images/dollar-2.jpg");
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}


.wrap-login100 {
  
  width: 570px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

I am using bootstrap 4 and I am looking for responsive height for `wrap-login100` instead of full height. Let me know if here anyone can help me for same. Thanks!

Edit: if I remove `min-height: 100vh;` from container-login100, its getting responsive but my background getting cut and getting visible in half screen only.

Comment: any flexbox elemnt has set by default align-items:stretch; try to set this property to your container as flex-start for example. [Docs](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks for hint, since I am new in HTML and CSS, its making me confused and not working after some try, can you please give me example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height:max-content` to `.wrap-login100` in css

```css
.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.container-login100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: top;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url("../images/dollar-2.jpg");
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.wrap-login100 {
  width: 570px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-login100">
  <div class="wrap-login100 ">
    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-32">
       Make Fast Cash Anywhere
    </span>
    <span class="login100-form-sub-title p-b-32">
       Begin Your Fast Start Steps Below...
    </span>
    <div class="test-progress" style="background-color:#ebebeb;">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success  progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:4%; background-color:#00c479;"><span id="progress">&nbsp;&nbsp;0% </span></div>
    </div>
    <form class="login100-form">
      <div id="quiz">
        <div class="question">
          <h3>
            <span id="question"> Are you looking for a way to make money online?</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="text-center" style="list-style-position: inside">
          <li>
            <input type="radio" id="a-option" name="selector" value="1">
            <label for="a-option" class="element-animation">Yes</label>
            <div class="check"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" id="b-option" name="selector" value="3">
            <label for="b-option" class="element-animation">No</label>
            <div class="check">
              <div class="inside"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="lic" style="display:none">
            <input type="radio" id="c-option" name="selector" value="3">
            <label for="c-option" class="element-animation">C</label>
            <div class="check">
              <div class="inside"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="lid" style="display:none">
            <input type="radio" id="d-option" name="selector" value="3">
            <label for="d-option" class="element-animation">D</label>
            <div class="check">
              <div class="inside"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```